# The plots of co-variance functions should start from 0-shift

Tags: plotting

**The following was my question given by my teacher,**

> 1. Generate a sequence of N = 1000 independent observations of random variable with distribution:     (c) Exponential with parameter λ = 1 , by
>    inversion method.
> 2. Present graphically obtained sequences(except for those generated in point e) i.e. e.g.    (a)     i. plot in the coordinates (no. obs.,
>    value of the obs)         ii. plot in the coordinates (obs no n, obs. no n +
>    i) for i = 1, 2, 3.       iii. plot so called covariance function for some
>    values. i.e. and averages:
>
> [image]

**I have written the following code,**

```
(*****************************************************************)
(*Task 01(c) and 02(a)*)
(*****************************************************************)
n = 1000;

taskC = Table[-Log[RandomReal[]], {n}];

ListPlot[taskC, AxesLabel->{"No. obs", "value of the obs"}]

i = 1;
ListPlot[Table[
    {taskC[[k]], taskC[[k+i]]}, 
    {k, 1, n-i,1}],
AxesLabel->{"obs.no.n", "obs.no.n+1"}]

i++;
ListPlot[Table[
    {taskC[[k]], taskC[[k+i]]},
    {k, 1, n-i,1}],
AxesLabel-> {"obs.no.n", "obs.no.n+2"}]

i++;
ListPlot[Table[
    {taskC[[k]], taskC[[k+i]]},
    {k,1,n-i,1}],
AxesLabel->{"obs.no.n", "obs.no.n+3"}]

avg = (1/n)*Sum[taskC[[i]], {i,n}];

ListPlot[Table[1/(n-tau) * Sum[(taskC[[i]]-avg)*(taskC[[i+tau]] - avg), n], {tau, 1,100}], 
    Joined->True, 
    AxesLabel->"Covariance Function"]
```

[image]

**He has commented,**

> The plots of co-variance functions should start from 0-shift. Note
> that for larger than 0 shifts you are estimating co-variance between
> independent observations which is zero, while for 0 shift you are
> estimating variance of observation which is large. Thus the contrast
> between these two cases is a clear indication that the observations
> are uncorrelated.

What did I do wrong?

How can I correct my code?

Comment: What explanation did your teacher provide?

Comment: @wolfies, he just mailed me this small text. And told me that I got 3 out of 5 points.

Comment: Why not mail him back? Who better to answer the question?